# как в combobox pyqt получить item'ы из функции

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcombobox

Псевдокод:

```
def bla():
    for i in range(5):
        return i

comboBox.setItemText(bla())
```

Для тех кто ищет ответ на вопрос, прикреплю его здесь:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox

def bla():
    a = 'a'
    b = 2
    return a, b

app = QApplication([])

comboBox = QComboBox()

for i in bla():
    comboBox.addItem("item_" + str(i))
comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(comboBox)
mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QComboBox::setItemText(int index, const QString &text)
>
> Устанавливает текст для элемента по указанному индексу в выпадающем списке.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox

def bla():                                                              # <---
    return "Поменяли текст и ..."                                       # <---

app = QApplication([])

comboBox = QComboBox()

for i in range(5):
    comboBox.addItem("item_" + str(i + 1))

# QStandardItemModel, метод model.item возвращает объекты QStandardItem
model = comboBox.model()

# Указываем какие элементы сделать невыбираемыми
model.item(0).setEnabled(False)
model.item(2).setEnabled(False)
model.item(4).setEnabled(False)

comboBox.setItemText(3, bla())                                              # <---
comboBox.setCurrentIndex(3)     # спозиционировали по номеру индекса

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(comboBox)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]